# Have two divs scroll to separate parts when clicking a link - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to have my page split into two sides, when I click a link I would like the left hand side to scroll down n amount and the right and side to scroll to a different n amount.

I am trying to use scrollToView however this is proving difficult.

```
  const test = useRef(null)
  const temp = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    test.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
    temp.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
  })
return (
<div>
  <div
    id="left"
    style={{
      width: "50%",
      float: "left",
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        height: "95vh",
        overflow: "hidden",
      }}
    >
      <div id="okay" style={{ height: "95vh" }}>
        1
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "95vh" }}>2</div>
      <div ref={test} style={{ height: "95vh" }}>
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" style={{ width: "50%", float: "right" }}>
    <div
      style={{
        height: "95vh",
        overflow: "hidden",
      }}
    >
      <div id="okay" style={{ height: "95vh" }}>
        1
      </div>
      <div ref={temp} style={{ height: "95vh" }}>
        2
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "95vh" }}>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

)

for example I would like the left to slide to the 3rd div and the right to slide to the 2nd

Comment: Please include example html, css and js code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How could we begin to help you since you provided no code at all? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).